# Checking if the value in various columns somehow match the value in one specific column

Tags: excel, textmatching

I have a huge database and I want to check if the value (different words) in the range `H:V` matches what's in column `D`, just a word would be matched in this case.

Here what it would look like:

```
Columns    A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O ...
Rows   1   Something           Green   Other 
       2   Something
       3   Something     Green        Blue
       4   Something          Violet
       5   Something
       6   Something       Blue
       7   Something              Dark
       8
       9
       10
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this need to be row by row (like checking H1 against D1)?

Comment: That would be great, if possible. I need to check if everything with a value from H1:V1 somehow matches D1

Comment: So, it is like H1, I1, J1 all against D1 separately?

Comment: Some columns and rows will be empty, if that matters.

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for, and where does the output go?

Comment: I just want to know if a word in different rows matches the whole sentence in column D. If it's a formula I'm going to use Column X for my output either as a Yes or No

Comment: OK...so then it will be yes only if each and every cell in the range H1:V1 = D1?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect because like I said some will be empty so I assume the output will be No. Thanks for helping me out, I'm still getting this whole excel formulas thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `=IF(COUNTIF($H1:$V1,$H1)=15,IF($H1=$D1,"Yes","No"),"No")`.  You can put this in Column X and autofill down.  It works by checking if all values in the range `H1:V1` are equal.  If not, the formula will return "No," while if yes, the formula will check and see if the values equal the value in `D1`.  If so, it returns "Yes."  If not, it returns "No."

EDIT:

For checking if any one cell matches, use this: `=IF(HLOOKUP($D1,$H1:$V1,1)=$D1,"Yes","No")`.  It will return `#N/A` if it's D reference is blank.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much. I just have one question, it's not giving me any YES. How do we make it Yes as results even if only 1 word matches what's on column D?

Comment: No. There's always something on it. H:V may have a few blank rows but that's ok.